# What is the measure of this set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fractional-part

I was wondering what is the 2 dimensional Lebesgue measure of this set

$\Gamma^2 := \{ (\{at\},\{bt\}) \; : \; t \in \mathbb{R} \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

Where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of ,$x$ (for example $\{\pi\} = 0.1415\dots$ and $a,b$ are two irrational numbers such that $a/b$ is irrational

Comment: Isn't this just a subset of a line, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Novice: It's the line with slope $b/a$, but with all points transported down to the unit square. So, for example, if $a = e$ and $b = \pi$, then at $t = 1$, we would transport the point $(e, \pi)$ down to $(e-2, \pi-3)$.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks. I guess it's trickier than I thought.

Comment: It's a countable union of line segments, so...

Comment: The hypothesis of $a$ and $b$ been irrational is not really important, as long as $a/b$ is irrational.

Comment: @jjagmath You're thinking of the proof that $\Gamma^2$ is dense in $[0,1]^2$?  Showing the Lebesgue measure is zero works for arbitrary real $a,b$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring You're right, but I think the OP intention was to ask about the case where the set is dense. The hypothesis about irrationality suggest the OP realized that when $a/b$ is rational, the question becomes trivial.

Comment: @BrianMoehring you're right, it was way easier than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I_{j, k}^2 = [j, j + 1) \times[k, k+1)$ for $j, k \in \mathbb Z$. The set $T_{I_{j, k}^2} = \{ t \in \mathbb R \colon (at, bt) \in I_{j, k}^2 \}$ is an interval (or empty) in $\mathbb R$. If $\gamma$ is the map such that $\gamma(t) = \left( at, bt \right)$, then $\gamma(T_{I_k^2}) \subset I_{j, k}^2$ is a line, and we know that $\lambda^2\left(\gamma(T_{I_{j, k}^2})\right) = 0$.

If $\gamma^*$ is the map such that $\gamma^*(t) = \left( \{at\}, \{bt\} \right)$, then $\lambda^2\left(\gamma^*(T_{I_{j, k}^2})\right) = \lambda^2\left(\gamma(T_{I_{j, k}^2})\right) = 0$ by translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure. Therefore

\begin{align*}
\lambda^2\left(\bigcup_{j = -\infty}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \gamma(T_{I_{j, k}^2})\right) &= \sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \lambda^2\left( \gamma(T_{I_{j, k}^2})\right)\\
&= \underbrace{\sum_{j = -\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \lambda^2\left( \gamma^*(T_{I_{j, k}^2})\right)}_{= 0}\\
&\geq \lambda^2\left(\bigcup_{j = -\infty}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \gamma^*(T_{I_{j, k}^2})\right)\\
&= \lambda^2\left(\gamma^*(\mathbb R)\right)\\
&= \lambda^2\left(\Gamma^2\right)
\end{align*}